# Creating an observer-able variable in Swift for MVVM pattern

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mvvm

I'm trying to observe a variable for it's change. The below code works, but when I set the initial value of `isValid` the observer is fired. Then after the my `callAPI()` the variable `isValid` is set again. So part of my logic code is being checked prematurely.

What is the correct way to implement an observer of so that on initial load, the initial setting of the value isn't fired?

Am I doing this all wrong? Is there a better way?

**The ViewController**

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let viewModel = SignInViewModel()
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // I want to watch this variable, but when it is initialized, it's already false and fires off the bad() func
        viewModel.isValid.bind {[weak self] isValid in
            if(isValid){
                self?.good()
            }  else {
                self?.bad()
            }
        }
        
        viewModel.callAPI()

    }
    
    private func bad(){
        print("VALID --")
    }

    private func bad(){
        print("-- NOT VALID")
    }
}
```

**My ViewModel**

```
public class SomeViewModel {
    
    lazy var isValid = Observer(false)
    
    func callAPI(){
        // Do something on the background and set the boolean
        isValid.value = //result
    }
}
```

**The Observer**

```
final class Observer<T> {
    typealias Listener = (T) -> Void
  
    var listener: Listener?
    var value: T {
        didSet {
            listener?(value)
        }
    }

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func bind(listener: Listener?) {
        self.listener = listener
        listener?(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the initial fire of your `listener` by modifying `Observer` to something like this:

```
final class Observer<T> {
    typealias Listener = (T) -> Void
  
    var listener: Listener?
    var value: T {
        didSet {
            listener?(value)
        }
    }

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func bind(listener: Listener?) {
        self.listener = listener
    }
    
    func bindAndFire(listener: Listener?) {
        self.listener = listener
        listener?(value)
    }
}
```

calling `bind(listener:)` function will only add the new listener without immediately calling it, while calling `bindAndFire(listener:)` will also fire the listener for the initial value.

Or you can use a `Bool` parameter in `bind(listener:)` function to determine whether you want or you don't want to fire the listener for the initial value:

```
func bind(fire: Bool = false, listener: Listener?) {
    self.listener = listener
    if fire {
        listener?(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* Why didn't I think of that? Thank you!

Comment: @gcharita Is there any way to add a single observer for multiple events? In the example, it binds the bool value. When it comes to complex view models there are multiple values will be emitted and in Android, we use sealed classes to handle the emitted values as events. Is it possible to implement the same here?

Comment: @KZoNE the answer's implementation uses generic `T` to determine the type of the captured value. That means that you can use it with any type, including an **enum**, which seams to be the type you are looking for. e.g. If you have a `State` enum type with `active` and `inactive` as cases, you can have a variable like this `var state = Observer(State.inactive)`